# Is there a way to impose some methods to a class without specify the parameters?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

I have a class named MANAGER

```
  public abstract class MANAGER
{


}
```

Nothing complex :-)

This class have multiple subclasses
example AD_MANAGER

```
  public class AD_MANAGER : MANAGER
{
    #region MEMBRES


    private AD_PROVIDER ad_provider;
    #endregion

    //================================================================================

    #region ACCESSEURS


    public AD_PROVIDER Ad_provider
    {
        get { return ad_provider; }
        set { ad_provider = value; }
    }
    #endregion

    //================================================================================

    #region CONSTRUCTORS

    public AD_MANAGER()
    {
        this.ad_provider = new AD_PROVIDER();
    }



    #endregion

    //================================================================================

    #region Public methods

    #region Get

     Stuff Here ..

    #endregion
    #endregion


}
```

And other ones.. Each Manager "manage" a specific class, named ENTITE. So for AD_MANAGER is used to manage a AD_ENTITE the ENTITE class contains only fields no methods..

So here's my question:
How can I specify that every MANAGER class have to implement a method for example isNull() but with parameters of type _ENTITE class related..

So AD_MANAGER Have to implement a `bool isnull(AD_ENTITE aENTITE)` method, and PERS_MANAGER Have to implement `bool isnull(PERS_ENTITE aPERS)` method.

With interface you can't declare `bool isnull(anytype);` So how can I do this such thing?

Thank you for trying to help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an interface:

```
public interface IAdManager<T>
{
     bool IsNull(T obj);
}
```

Then your client classes need to implement `IAdManager` like:

```
public class AD_MANAGER : MANAGER, IAdManager<AD_MANAGER>
```

Comment: for you what is the best? Generic class like Andee answer or generic interface?

Comment: Depends. I prefer an interface, but when you are really needing an Abstract Class; just add the method to the class.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, generics probably will help.

```
public abstract class MANAGER<T>
{
    public abstract bool isnull(T item);
}
```

and

```
public class AD_MANAGER : MANAGER<Ad_provider>
{
    public override bool isnull(Ad_provider item) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Good idea.. What is the best? generic class or generic interface? Tx

Comment: It's entirely up to you and depends on your program structure. If you have code common to all manager classes, use the generic class as you only need to write it once. Otherwise go for the interface as it'll allow you to implement that interface if you need to inherit another class.

Answer (score 0):

Generics should help you achieve this, I guess!

Answer (score 0):

Can you use two different interfaces IAd_Manager and IPers_Manager?

Or alternatively declare the method as:

bool isnull(T myParam);